# auto-commit with pandas to_sql using sqlalchemy with sqlite

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

In the case of sqlite, it is not clear whether we can easily commit right after each dataframe insert. (Assuming that auto-commit is off by default, following the python database wrapping convention).

Using the simplest sqlalchemy api flow ―

```
db_engine = db.create_engine()
for .....
   # slowly compute some_df, takes a lot of time
   some_df.to_sql(con = db_engine)
```

How can we make sure that every `.to_sql` is committed?

For motivation, imagine the particular use case being that each write reflects the result of a potentially very long computation and we do not want to lose a huge batch of such computations nor any single one of them, in case a machine goes down or in case the python sqlalchemy engine object is garbage collected before all its writes have actually drained in the database.

I believe auto-commit is off by default, and for sqlite, there is no way of changing that in the `create_engine` command. What might be the simplest, safest way for adding auto-commit behavior ― or explicitly committing after every dataframe write ― when using the simplistic `.to_sql` api?

Or must the code be refactored to use a different api flow to accomplish that?

Comment: `db_engine = db_engine.execution_options(autocommit=True)`?

Comment: This should work. I failed to find it myself while being lost in the somewhat complicated API docs of the involved three libraries. You can post that as an answer I guess.

Comment: SQLA engine is in autocommit mode by default, at least in versions up to 1.3. "in case the python sqlalchemy engine object is garbage collected before all its writes have actually drained in the database" seems like something that's not going to happen.

Comment: @IljaEveril [are you absolutely sure?](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html#autocommit-mode)

Comment: Yes. The link you pasted refers to (ORM) **sessions**, which can use an engine as their bind, but are not engines.

Answer (score 2):

You can [set the connection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html?highlight=autocommit#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.autocommit) to autocommit by:

```
db_engine = db_engine.execution_options(autocommit=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit:

> The “autocommit” feature is only in effect when no `Transaction` has otherwise been declared. This means the feature is not generally used with the ORM, as the `Session` object by default always maintains an ongoing `Transaction`.

In your code you have not presented any explicit transactions, and so the **engine** used as the `con` is in autocommit mode (as implemented by SQLA).

Note that SQLAlchemy implements its own autocommit that is independent from the DB-API driver's possible autocommit / non-transactional features.

Hence the "the **simplest**, safest way for adding auto-commit behavior ― or explicitly committing after every dataframe write" is what you already had, unless `to_sql()` emits some funky statements that SQLA does not recognize as data changing operations, which it has not, at least of late.

It might be that the SQLA autocommit feature is on the way out in the next major release, but we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it's fair to say that this behavior is barely deducible for mere mortals, from the referenced documentation section, so this is helpful. I'd improve that section for bottom-line greater clarity if I were the maintainers. Or make it obvious that auto-commit _is_ the default after all when there's no explicit transaction in user code.

Comment: And thanks for the heads-up about the possible future change.

Comment: I keep [the other solution to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58157494/1509695) in my code, for future compatibility.